# Postgres keeps single quotes for string pushed into an array

Tags: javascript, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I've got a table with (simplifying) `id` (UUID) and `transactions` (Array of JSON as `text`) columns. I need to update a specific row by its ID so as to push a new element into a `transactions` array. The problem is - when I add another element into existing array I get single quotes around.

Let's say there is a `{"a":1,"b":2}` value in the column by `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` ID.

I do something like this (TypeScript, TypeORM):

```
getConnection().query(
  `
    UPDATE public.my_table
    SET transactions[array_length(transactions, 1) + 1] = $2
    WHERE id = $1
  `,
  new Array<any>('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', JSON.stringify({ c: 3, d: 4 }))
);
```

Now the updated column value will be like that:

```
{{"a":1,"b":2},'{"c":3,"d":4}'}
```

Is that possible to fix?

*I use array of `text` instead of array of `json` because TypeORM automatically parses JSON data into JS objects and I don't need to spend CPU time on that. As far as I understand from PG docs, `text` and `json` are the same, the only difference is JSON validity guarantee that I don't need here (I assume, with JSON column this UPDATE would fail), so it doesn't seem relevant to this issue.*

Comment: I would you the json (jsonb) datatype to store json data. That would also solve your current problem

Comment: I can't remember why I didn't use `jsonb` type. I might need to check it again, but it would be really great to solve the issue with `text` column type. Not to change existing table / data.

Comment: Aw, actually, I remember now. `jsonb` is indexed (thus, you can select a value from some specific "object" property), so it doesn't seem to be a performant solution for my case. There are hundreds of million records in the table and JSON items in array might be quite big. I don't need indexes here at all. The `text` type looks like a most performant and appropriated way to keep the data. Although, I might be wrong, will be thankful for any correction.

Comment: Just don't build index when you don't need an index. There is no index by default.

Comment: Maybe I used the wrong word for it. I meant the key->value relations in `jsonb`. If you can search by JSON key... does it mean that PG "indexes" this JSON and keeps relations somewhere in the memory? This doesn't seem performant. Sorry, I wan't able to find some meaningful explanation for that thing so I'd better ask.